# Skip data in excel bar chart

Tags: excel, charts

I have a big series of data in excel and I want to plot it using a bar chart. The trick is that I need to skip the error cells, not as 0 or gaps, but just not adding the series:

```
Column A   Column B
   A          10
   B          15
  na()        na()
   D          6
```

...and I want my plot to have A, B and D (WITHOUT THE C) on the y axis and values in the x axis.

This is just a simplification of course...the data set is much bigger, that is why I cannot hide rows or stuff like that

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To hide a series just hide the underlying row / column. So, in your case you can simply hide the column `C`:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("C").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

If you have a range for your series then you can scan it for errors and hide the ones that contain errors with the following sub:

```
Sub tmpTest()

Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z100")
    If VarType(cell.Value) = vbError Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns(cell.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @Ralph ...The problem is that I can´t hide the rows because of other charts and tables involved...Do you know any other way to do it?

Comment: Solution: remove the series from the graph or copy the relevant data to another sheet where you can then hide the underlying data without problems. *Note, that Excel itself will also hide a column / row if that shouldn't be shown in a graph: just implement a pivot table with a graph and de-select a series and the underlying data in the pivot table will be hidden. So, if you have an adjacent table to the pivot table then this one gets also partially hidden.*